# Validation input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

In this mini deposit app I need to validate the input field for 3 different things. With error message that states "Can not be blank", "only numerical values", and "no negative numbers". I have the functionality but tried to implement validation and failed. This is the code without any validation.

```
function Deposit(){
const ctx = React.useContext(UserContext);
const [totalState, setTotalState] = React.useState(0);

    let transactionState = 0; // state of this transaction
    let status = `Current Balance $ ${totalState}`;
    console.log("Render Account");
    
    const handleChange = event => {
    console.log(`handleChange ${event.target.value}`);
    transactionState = Number(event.target.value);
    };
    
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    setTotalState(totalState + transactionState);
    event.preventDefault();
    };
    
    const ATMDeposit = ({ onChange }) => {
    return (
      <label className="label huge">
        Deposit Amount:
        <input type="number" onChange={onChange}></input>
        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-light" value="Deposit"></input>
      </label>
        );
    };

return (
<Card
bgcolor="primary"
header="Deposit"
body={(
<>
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

<h3>{status}</h3>
<ATMDeposit onChange={handleChange}> Deposit</ATMDeposit>
 </form>
    </>
    )}
    />
  ) 
}
```

I have implemented the validation code suggested, greatly appreciated, and now validation works! I only need to figure out why the functionality isn't working. The value gets taken from **handleChange** but it does not add it to **setTotalState**. I tried adding Number constructor in **handleChange** like I originally had but it did not work. This is what I have now.

```
function Deposit(){
    
    const [show, setShow]  = React.useState(true);
    const [errors, setErrors]  = React.useState([]);
    const [num, setNum]  = React.useState('');
    const [totalState, setTotalState] = React.useState(0);
    const ctx = React.useContext(UserContext);

    let transactionState = 0; // state of this transaction
    let status = `Current Balance $ ${totalState}`;
    console.log("Render Account");


    function validate(value){
        const errorsList = [];
          if (!value.trim()){
            errorsList.push('Error: Cannot be empty');
          }
          if (/^[-0-9]*$/.test(value) === false){
            errorsList.push('Error: only numbers');
          }
          if (/^[-0-9]*$/.test(value) === true && value < 0) {
            errorsList.push('Error: negative values not allowed');
          }
      
          if (errorsList.length) {
            setErrors(errorsList);
            setTimeout(() => setErrors(''),3000)
            return false;
          }
          return true;
      }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (!validate(num)){
        setShow(false);
        } 
        if (validate(num)) {
        setTotalState(totalState + transactionState);
        event.preventDefault;
        }
    }

    const handleChange = event => {
        console.log(`handleChange ${event.target.value}`);
        transactionState = setNum(event.target.value);
    }
    

    return(
        <Card
        bgcolor="primary"
        header= "Make deposit"
        status={errors}
        body={(
            <>
            <h3>{status}</h3>
            Deposit Amount<br/>
            <input type="input" className="form-control" id="num" value={num} onChange={handleChange}></input><br/>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-light" onClick={handleSubmit}>Deposit</button>
            </>
        )}
        />
        
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change errors to array

```
const [errors, setErrors]  = React.useState([]);
```

and here is validation function

```
function validate(value){
  const errorsList = [];
    if (!value.trim()){
      errorsList.push('Error: Cannot be empty');
    }
    if (/^[-0-9]*$/.test(value) === false){
      errorsList.push('Error: only numbers');
    }
    if (/^[-0-9]*$/.test(value) === true && value < 0) {
      errorsList.push('Error: negative values not allowed');
    }

    if (errorsList.length) {
      setErrors(errorsList);
      setTimeout(() => setError(''),3000)
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}

validate("1!") // false
validate("123") // true
```

Hope this will help